# Data transfer between 2 classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

There are 2 classes (AAAA and BBBB)
I want to send data from method b1 in BBBB class to method a1 in AAAA class. How can I do this in the simplest way?

I did the following but it didn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
class AAAA{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('AAAA Is Started');
        this.a1 = this.a1.bind(this);
    }

    a1(number1, number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}


class BBBB{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('BBBB Is Started');
        this.b1 = this.b1.bind(this);
    }

    b1(number1, number2)
    {
        AAAA.a1(number1, number2);
    }
}





$(document).ready(function () {

    const aa = new AAAA();
    const bb = new BBBB();

    bb.b1(2,2);

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isnt it because method b1 does not have access to a1?
How about pass the new instance of AAAA, to the b1 method, and use it to call its method a1?

```js
class AAAA{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('AAAA Is Started');
        this.a1 = this.a1.bind(this);
    }

    a1(number1, number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }
}


class BBBB{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('BBBB Is Started');
        this.b1 = this.b1.bind(this);
    }

    b1(number1, number2, aa)
    {
        aa.a1(number1, number2);
    }
}





$(document).ready(function () {

    const aa = new AAAA();
    const bb = new BBBB();

    bb.b1(2,2, aa);

})
```

Comment: I did not know exactly how to communicate these 2 classes. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Frenchy I did not understand. is there any other solution?